# 4 electrical lines into one ceiling box

Tags: ceiling-fan, light

[image]I just installed a ceiling fan and light and not sure how to wire it.  The wall switch box has 2 switches, one for a closet ceiling light and the other is to operate my new ceiling fan.  In the picture with the 6 wires, the black wire to the right is the only hot one.  The two wires to the left, when tested with my ohm meter showed it was for the closet light switch. So the middle 2 wires must be for the new ceilin fan. enter image description here[image]In the second picture are the white/black/ground wires that appear to operate the nonworking wall outlets that are in the room. The ground wires are all hooked up and taped in the box Can someone tell me how to wire this correctly please?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring in both switch boxes please?

Comment: I trust that you mean you tested those wires with a voltmeter and not an ohmmeter.  And concur with @ThreePhaseEel that it would be very helpful to see the second picture you mention in the post.

Comment: Yes on the voltmeter. Sorry about the missing pic. Took it, added it, apparently wasn't there.